# How do I find matching data from two tables?

Tags: sql

Sorry for the lack of experience in advance.

I have cleansed my diagnostics table and want extract just the rows from followup questions that share the same string in both the `AssetType` and `RepairType` columns as the diagnostics table.

Is there a statement or join I can do that will bring back those results?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you can do is perform an inner join from diagnostics to followupquestions:

```
SELECT * FROM 
    Diagnostics D
INNER JOIN
    FollowupQuestions F
ON
    D.AssetType = F.AssetType
    AND
    D.RepairType = F.RepairType
```

An inner join will only return rows where the ON condition is met.

Comment: Pro tip: create a wiki somewhere and put stuff like this in there so you always have a place to refer back to. This is a fairly simple one, but you can build on it as you progress.